# Add more widget areas to a theme

Tags: themes, widgets

what's the best approach to add more widget areas to a theme? currently, my theme has 2 columns that display the widgets, but I'd like to extend it to 4 for example.

It currently looks like this:
[image]

And I'd like it to look like this:
[image]

All the widgets of this theme are located above the footer. The theme is called Time by s5themes.com. The widget initializer is not located in the functions.php as far as I know. Is this a simple fix at all? thanks!

Edit: Now that the sidebar is displaying in the theme, I think the rest of how each sidebar is shown is located in the style.css. Thanks.

Comment: Best for what? What are the alternatives you may select from?

Comment: Basically, I just want to be able to display something like the picture I showed. I tried adding one more widget function to where the widgets are managed (widget.php in theme/admin/inc) with no result.

Comment: because you need to add sidebars and not widgets. What is wrong with Manolo's answer?

Comment: have you read a tutorial on how to add sidebars and widgets?

Comment: Because adding a sidebar in the admin is just the first step, now you need to change the theme's code to  display the sidebars.

Comment: Ouch! I finally got them to show, sorry about that. They appear stacked in the same 2 vertical columns. I wonder how could I add HTML to 'before_widget', 'after_widget', 'before_title' and 'after_title' to display the sidebar in its own column and not stacked with the 2 existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this code in the `functions.php` file:

```
/**
 * Register new sidebar
 *
 */
function new_sidebar_widget_init() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'new-sidebar',
    'id' => 'new-sidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div id="new-sidebar">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '',
    'after_title' => '',
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'new_sidebar_widget_init' );
```

and then call the sidebar from a template to display it:

```
<?php  dynamic_sidebar( 'new-sidebar' ); ?>
```

Comment: As in my post, the widgets in this theme are managed on a widget.php file and not in the functions.php. I tried adding the code above anyway to no avail. Also tried adding it in the widget.php file also with no luck. Thanks

Comment: @manolo, this is half an answer, to make it a full one you should also explain how to get the sidebar to be displayed on the frontend.

Comment: @MarkKaplun - Done it.